# Can INSERT with ON CONFLICT in PostgreSQL be conditional in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL query:

```
WITH inserted_id AS (
    INSERT INTO users (email,name,user_id,user_name,source)
        VALUES (
                'a',
                'b',
                'c',
                'd',
                'e')
        ON CONFLICT (email) DO UPDATE SET
            user_id='c',
            user_name='d',
            source='e'
        RETURNING id AS users_id
)
INSERT INTO users_groups (users_id, groups_id)
SELECT users_id, 5 FROM inserted_id;
```

I would like the second `INSERT` to `users_groups` to be conditional on the first `INSERT` being done without any conflicts — that is, the `ON CONFLICT` part is not run. Can this be done with the query or what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something in the `on conflict`, so the row will be returned.

I think you can do:

```
INSERT INTO users_groups (users_id, groups_id)
    SELECT users_id, 5
    FROM inserted_id
    WHERE users_id <> 'aa';
```

If you can, you can simply use `on conflict do nothing`.  Then the id will not be returned.

Comment: Sorry my example where off. I have update so your answer does not work.